# Historical Report Generation Robotframework risto.py

Tags: robotframework

When I run `risto.py` to generate a historical report (graph), I am getting the following error:

```
#risto.py --output history.png output.xml output1.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/risto.py", line 505, in <module>
       Ristopy().main (sys.argv [1:])
    File "/usr/local/bin/risto.py", line 428, in main
       viewer_open = self.plot_one_graph (args)
    File "/usr/local/bin/risto.py", line 442, in _plot_one_graph
       output = self._plot (stats, opts)
    File "/usr/local/bin/risto.py", line 455, in _plot
       plotter = Plotter (opts['tag'], not opts['nocritical'],
KeyError: 'nocritical'

#risto.py --version
risto.py 1.0.2
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not doing any mistake. There is a bug in the risto.py code itself (line 461):

```
plotter = Plotter(opts['tag'],  not opts['nocritical'],
                      not opts['noall'], not opts['nototals'],
                      not opts['nopassed'], not opts['nofailed'],
                      opts['width'], opts['height'], opts['font'],
                      opts['marker'], opts['xticks'])
```

replace it with the follwing:

```
plotter = Plotter(opts['tag'],  opts['critical'],
                      opts['all'], opts['totals'],
                      opts['passed'], opts['failed'],
                      opts['width'], opts['height'], opts['font'],
                      opts['marker'], opts['xticks'])
```

Actually this is inside function def _plot(self, stats, opts): which is called by:

```
def _plot_one_graph(self, args):
    opts, paths = self._arg_parser.parse_args(args)
    stats = AllStatistics(paths, opts['namemeta'], opts['verbose'])
    output = self._plot(stats, opts)
    return output is None
```

If you print opts inside this function you will get the actual keys for the dictionary opts. After that I changed that above code snippet and now working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify and add the following functions to make the risto work:

```
def _plot_one_graph(self, args):
    opts, paths = self._arg_parser.parse_args(args)
    opts = self._handle_options(opts)
    stats = AllStatistics(paths, opts['namemeta'], opts['verbose'])
    output = self._plot(stats, opts)
    return output is None

def _handle_options(self, opts):
    if opts.get('critical') is None:
        opts['critical'] = True
    if opts.get('all') is None:
        opts['all'] = True
    if opts.get('totals') is None:
        opts['totals'] = True
    if opts.get('passed') is None:
        opts['passed'] = True
    if opts.get('failed') is None:
        opts['failed'] = True
    return opts
```

Please do a diff to get difference from your original file.